# How to change the volume in PulseAudio (libpulse)

Tags: c, audio, pulseaudio

I am writing a program to play audio using 'libpulse' on linux. I have successfully played the  `audio`, but need to know how to change the volume. I am able to start the stream using

```
v = PA_VOLUME_NORM;
pa_cvolume_set(&m_lcvolume, 1, v);
pa_stream_connect_playback(s, NULL, &attr, PA_STREAM_NOFLAGS, &m_lcvolume, NULL)
```

with pacific volume but need to know how to change the volume after connecting to stream. Dont want to call pa_stream_connect_playback function again and again to change the volume.

Comment: pactl set-sink-volume 0

Comment: I am asking `c` code to that using libpulse library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to change the volume of each channel by calling `pa_context_set_sink_input_volume`. The `pa_cvolume` parameter can be used to specify the volume and channel in `pa_context_set_sink_input_volume`.

Comment: I have two different audio streams that I'm trying to do independently, so your answer ( which modifies the shared sync ) doesn't work --- but does for you!